# Iterate through different view with array, Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, view

I have 4 different progressView

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstProgressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondProgressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdProgressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var fourthProgressBar: UIProgressView!
```

And I have an array with 4 values

```
[30,20,24,25]
```

Since this array change from the API call (I need to check if I really have this value), what is the best and safer way to:

- Order this array from bigger to smaller
- Iterate throught this array and set each of my progressView value to the corresponding array value

This is my current code:

```
func setupProgressBar(item: CustomObject) {
   let array = item.array // [x,y,z,w] array 

   self.progressBar.setProgress( ?? , animated: false)
}
```

I have an animation for the value but it's not the point of my question, i just need to set values

Comment: Which progress bar should get which array value? Also, what do you mean by the "best way"? Can you define that?

Comment: First progress bar => First array value ;
Second progress bar => Second array value and so on

Comment: With "Best way" I mean without setting one by one, and by doing it in a safe way (no crash cuz I don't have value for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to connect all the `UIProgressBar` in your storyboard to an `@IBOutlet` collection.

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressBars: [UIProgressView]!
```

Then iterate through the array to set the value of `progressBars`.

```
func setupProgressBar(item: CustomObject) {
    let array = item.array // [x,y,z,w] array
    for (progressBar, value) in zip(progressBars, array) {
        progressBar.setProgress(value, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, I didnt think about this! Could you add some specific code for my example? Let's say I have to add this 4 array values to this collection of ProgressBar

Comment: I've already added the modified `setupProgressBar` method as an example.

Comment: @Frankenstein question: what will happen if the count of progressBars and item.array are not equal? Will it crash?

Comment: That's a good point, I can try this out if @Frankenstein couldnt' help us!

Btw thank you very much, I learned 2 new stuff!

Comment: @MubashirAli It doesn't crash for that scenario. It's Safer!

Answer (score 2):

```
func setupProgressBar(item: CustomObject) {
    let valueArray = item.array.sorted  // [x,y,z,w] array
    let progressBars = [firstProgressBar, second….., fourthProgressBar]
    for item in valueArray.enumerated() {
        progressBars[item.index].setProgress(item.value)
    }
}
```

Make sure that progress bars and values are equal. Otherwise the code will crash.